# Visual Studio can't find headers

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio 2013. My is using CppUnit for unit tests.

During compilation, I get a :

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cppunit/TestFixture.h': No such file or directory
```

It comes from a file that includes the following headers:

```
//////////////////
// Unit testing //
//////////////////

#include <cppunit/TestFixture.h>
#include <cppunit/TestAssert.h>
#include <cppunit/TestCaller.h>
#include <cppunit/TestSuite.h>
#include <cppunit/TestCase.h>
```

In Debug/Project Properties... Configuration Properties/C-C++/General, the additional include directories is setup to :

```
C:\Users\Francois\Documents\cppunit-1.12.1\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

The file C:\Users\Francois\Documents\cppunit-1.12.1\include\cppunit\TestFixture.h does exist. I don't understand what might be wrong.

Comment: The `Include` folder contains a subfolder called `cppunit` with those files? Or do you actually have to rename `cppunit-1.12.1` to simply `cppunit` and add just `C:\Users\Francois\Documents\cppunit` to the additional include directories?

Comment: The folder C:\Users\Francois\Documents\cppunit-1.12.1\include does contain a folder cppunit which contains the file TestFixture.h.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I was in Debug mode and the stupid IDE Option was by default in Release mode :-(. Problem fixed.